# What does '#if _LFS64_LARGEFILE-0' mean to CPP?

Tags: c++, g++, c-preprocessor

What does `#if _LFS64_LARGEFILE-0` mean to the **C** Preprocessor for g++?  Is that a minus zero or is that part of the symbol?  If it is minus zero, how does that affect whether the `#if` is triggered?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is a more robust version of:

```
#if _LFS64_LARGEFILE
```

i.e. that the code should be conditionally included if `_LFS64_LARGEFILE` has a true value.

Adding the `- 0`, prevents you from getting a warning (`#if with no expression`) when `_LFS64_LARGEFILE` is not defined.